# Windows phone 8 send image in tile notification

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns, live-tile

I want to send a tile notification from one device to another.
Is it possible to send an image from the phone's isolated storage in a tile notification?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

The images on tiles must either be on the device that is displaying them or online. As only a Uri is passed in the notification message it's not possible to include an encoded image in the payload.

If you want to capture an image on one device and then display it on another it will first need to be uploaded to a public location on the web or sent between the devices in another way.

Comment: how can I send a picture between devices?